# owner of a file should be user 'nobody' and group 'anybody'

Tags: server, nfs, mountpoint

I have exported 2 filesystems on an Ubuntu server 14.04 and mounted them from another Ubuntu server 14.04.

In my /etc/exports file on the server, I deactivated the option no_root_squash for one of the mount points. I created a test file in that mount point and it says the owner of the file is root but it should be the group 'anybody' and user 'nobody'. I would like any ideas on why this is happening. Here is a copy of my /etc/exports code that I am using.

```
/home 192.168.0.101(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)
/var/nfs 192.168.0.101(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you meant was: I've mounted the NFS exported directory from an NFS client and created a file on that client then I'd say this is working as intended.

You mounted an exported FS which had a no_root_squash option enabled and the file created on the client is owned by 'root'. That's actually what the no_root_squash option does.

```
root_squash
    Map requests from uid/gid 0 to the anonymous uid/gid. Note that this does not apply to any other uids or gids that might be equally sensitive, such as user bin or group staff. 
no_root_squash
    Turn off root squashing. This option is mainly useful for diskless clients.
```

I'd say you need to remove no_root_squash if mapping root to nobody is what you're after.